# How do I use flexbox within a wrapper?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Having some trouble trying to design a specific section with flexbox, but also within a wrapper.

What I need to do is make it look like below:

[image: target]

Currently, my code looks like the below:

[image: now]

Here are my HTML/CSS codes:

```css
.feature p {
  font-size: 39px;
  color: #333333;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.feature {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background: #F6F8FA;
  height: 425px;
}

.firstSection {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<section class="firstSection">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/400" alt="van driving on a road next to a hill">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="surfer on ocean">
    <div class="feature">
      <h2>Feature</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
      <a href="http://google.com" class="blueButton">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If I try to add a wrapper as a second class to the , it completely distorts and not what I'm looking to get. I also tried adding another  tag as a child of the  tag, but that didn't work either. HELP!

The wrapper snippet is below:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1140px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I edit your post for you. replace the `./image-1.jpeg` and the `./image-2.jpeg` images with real images of your project. it's easy, upload it on the editor of Stack Overflow and then use the uploaded images link inside code snippet.

Comment: Your code works as expected i don't understand what's the problem.

Comment: So you see how theres white space around the section in the final design that I'm trying to achieve? That's because there is a wrapper around it. Every time I try to add a wrapper, the layout of the section we are looking at becomes distorted

Comment: Is it an issue that can not be solved by adding the appropriate margins / paddings?

Comment: @AmerllicA Do not do that! You replaced his markup which might be part of the problem! Plus, you've linked to a third party site. What happens to this question when that link breaks?

Comment: Dear @Rob, I know about edition rules. Changing codes a bad action. I just rearrange the code, fix the indent. and put them inside the code snippet. I do not replace or change.

Comment: @SwimmerF I'm trying to avoid that because the section should fit within the wrapper. I just need to fit it in the wrapper then i'll be able to play around with paddings and margins